# ValueError in scrapy __init__ arg

Tags: python, scrapy

When i am writing this command in cmd

scrapy crawl quotes -o item.csv -a u=test_user_name -a p=test_passporw_name -a urls=http://books.toscrape.com/

It's showing

raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.contrib.spiders.init import InitSpider
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class QuotesSpider(InitSpider):
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    login_page='http://quotes.toscrape.com/login'
    start_urls = ['']
    username=''
    password=''

    def __init__(self,u,p,urls):
        self.username=u
        self.password=p
        self.start_urls=urls




    def init_request(self):
        #"""This function is called before crawling starts."""
        return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
        csrf_token=response.xpath('//*[@name="csrf_token"]//@value').extract_first()
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                         formdata={'csrf_token': csrf_token,
                                                   'username': self.username,
                                                   'password': self.password,
                                                   },
                                         callback=self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self, response):
        # open_in_browser(response)
        #"""Check the response returned by a login request to see if we aresuccessfully logged in."""
        if "Logout" in response.body:
            self.log("\n\n\nSuccessfully logged in. Let's start crawling!\n\n\n")
            # Now the crawling can begin..

            return self.initialized() # ****THIS LINE FIXED THE LAST PROBLEM*****

        else:
            self.log("\n\n\nFailed, Bad times :(\n\n\n")
            # Something went wrong, we couldn't log in, so nothing happens.

    def parse(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.start_urls=urls` makes `start_urls` a string instead of a list.
This makes every character from that string interpreted as a url.

Just make `start_urls` a list instead, and your code should work:

```
self.start_urls = [urls]
```

Also, you don't need to initialize your variables to dummy values, or parse the csrf_token yourself (it will be done automatically when using `FormRequest.from_response()`)

On a side-note, your code looks like it is written for a fairly old version of scrapy - most of your imports have been moved, renamed or deprecated.
Maybe you should get your code refreshed by having a quick reread of the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use loginform library.

Try this code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from loginform import fill_login_form


class QuotesSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    login_url = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/login'

    login_user = 'your-username'
    login_password = 'secret-password-here'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(self.login_url, self.parse_login)

    def parse_login(self, response):
        data, url, method = fill_login_form(response.url, response.body,self.login_user, self.login_password)
        return scrapy.FormRequest(url, formdata=dict(data),method=method, callback=self.start_crawl)

    def start_crawl(self, response):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        quotes = response.xpath("//div[@class='quote']//span[@class='text']/text()").extract()
        yield {'quotes': quotes}
```

My tree structure can help you to organize files

```
tree .
.
├── scrapy.cfg
└── scrapy_spider
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── items.py
    ├── middlewares.py
    ├── pipelines.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   └── settings.cpython-36.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    └── spiders
        ├── example.py
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __pycache__
        │   ├── example.cpython-36.pyc
        │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
        │   └── quotes_spider.cpython-36.pyc
        └── quotes_spider.py
```

Comment: i need to use it on cmd "scrapy crawl quotes -o item.csv -a u=test_user_name -a p=test_passporw_name -a "

Comment: When i am writing this command in cmd

scrapy crawl quotes -o item.csv -a u=test_user_name -a p=test_passporw_name -a urls=http://books.toscrape.com/

It's showing

raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url) ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h

Comment: I can not try,bacause I do not know how to register. I have used similar code for logginin with Ubuntu.

Comment: There's no need for `loginform`, it is based on scrapy's `FormRequest`, and does nothing `FormRequest` can't do.